# Localization at primes and local ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm now studying localization. When $R$ is a commutative ring, I know that localization at a prime is a local ring. I have a question.

> Let $\mathfrak p_{1},\dots,\mathfrak p_{n}$ be primes of $R$ and set $S=R-\cup_{i=1}^n{\mathfrak p_{i}}$, then is localization $S^{-1}R$ a local ring?

Comment: it has only finitely many maximal
ideals

Comment: how to prove that ?

Comment: there is 1-1 correspondence between the prime ideals of $S^{-1} R$ and prime ideals of $R$ that have no intersection with S

Answer (score 4):

this is 5.35 of the book "Steps in Commutative Algebra" (by R. Y. Sharp). So hint from it:
[image]

and

[image]

so if there is no inclusion in {$p_{1},...,p_{n}$} then we have $n$ maximal ideals

Comment: maximals: $S^{-1}p_{1},...,S^{-1}p_{n}$